# Jquery -> Document.Ready -> Doesn't fire

Tags: jquery, document-ready

I'm running Mac OS 10.6, Chrome 34, and jQuery 2.1.1.
I have this simple code taken from TutsPlus '30 days to learn jQuery'.
I claim there's a bug in jQuery.
Or... you tell me! ;)

This doesn't work:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title> Does not work </title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>  //script is in root
  <style>
   .emphasis{font-weight: bold;}
  </style>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function()){$('li:first-child').addClass('emphasis');});
  </script>

 </head>
 <body>
  <ul>
   <li>Hello</li>
   <li>Hello 2</li>
   <li>Hello 3</li>
  </ul>
 </body>
</html>
```

This works:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title> </title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
  <style>
  .emphasis{font-weight: bold;}
  </style>


  </head>
 <body>

 <ul>
  <li>Hello</li>
  <li>Hello 2</li>
  <li>Hello 3</li>
 </ul>

  <script>
   $('li:first-child').addClass('emphasis');
  </script>

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: syntax error `$(document).ready(function () {
    $('li:first-child').addClass('emphasis');
});` -- extra `)` in `function())`

Comment: Hi and thanks for the answer. May I ask you, please, could you recommend an editor that has syntax checks?

Comment: there are lot of editors... Dreamviewer could be one I think... or you have aptana

Comment: Thank you very much Arun I will give Aptana a try!

Answer (score 2):

Try to remove that additional parenthesis,

```
$(document).ready(function()){$('li:first-child').addClass('emphasis');});
//--------------------------^
```

valid code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('li:first-child').addClass('emphasis');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

you mistakenly close the document ready function immedieatly. you closed extra one closed braces that why it will not work

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
             $('li:first-child').addClass('emphasis');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Change below line

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function()){$('li:first-child').addClass('emphasis');});
</script>
```

to ( as you got one extra `)` after `function()`)

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $('li:first-child').addClass('emphasis');
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove that close bracket which was added additionally.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('li:first-child').addClass('emphasis');
});
```